# Can you cook cut potatoes in a nonstick frying pan without oil?

Tags: potatoes, non-stick

Will it still cook properly this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would depend on the cut of the potatoes, the heat and whether or not you put a lid on your frying pan.

- If big cuts without a lid: They'll still be raw
- If cut into small dice, heat not too high, with a lid on, you'd basically steam the potatoes in their own moisture and that would work.
- if cut into small dice, high heat, no lid, you'll end up with charcoal on the outside and raw on the inside.

So yes, it's possible, *but it's going to be finicky* so if you don't want to use fat, what's wrong with:

- boiling them
- parboiling them and then putting them for a short while in a convection oven?